# Now that I know how to salt & hash passwords, a few more questions

Tags: authentication, hash, passwords, credentials, salt

So, let's assume I have read every article/post about appropriately salting and hashing passwords in order to secure user credentials.

This means I am **not** wondering what hashing algorithm to use (SHA1 vs. SHA2 vs. PDKBF2), how to generate the salt, how to store the salt, how to append the salt, or whether I should be writing the code myself vs. leveraging well-established libraries like bcrypt. Please, avoid rambling about these issues here as I have read 50+ other pages of that already.

Just assume the following is my approach (also note I understand this is not flawless or likely sufficient for applications like financial service, I am really just wondering if this is an acceptable min bar to claim that I "do the right thing").

- User comes to my amazing website (www.myamazingwebsite.com) and logs in with email and pass.
- I pull her salt and hash from my database. Assume the salt is lengthy enough, unique per-user, and created using a CSPRNG upon user registration.
- I prepend the salt to her input password, hash it using SHA-512, run 1,000 iterations, then compare it to the hashed value pulled from the db:

  ```
  var hash = sha512(salt + password);
  for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      hash = sha512(salt + password + hash);
  }
  ```
- If they match, the user is authenticated. Otherwise, they are not.

Now, my question is how secure is my above approach. The questions I would like help answering:

1. Do I need to change the salt periodically? For example, perhaps I could re-compute and store a new hash using a newly created random salt after every successful login. This seems like it would be more secure but I am not sure what standard practice is here.
2. The request to the server will be done via https. Does that mean I can assume that I can process all of the hashing and validation logic server side? Would most folks consider this sufficient, or do I need to consider some hybrid both on client and server side?
3. Anything else I am overlooking or need to consider?

Thanks in advance, I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

1) Assuming you've done the right thing and do not store their password, you can't change the salt unless they are logging in. I suppose you could change their salt every time they do log in, but it doesn't really help (and might hurt).

Here's why: Having a unique salt on everyone simply makes it harder for an attacker that has access to your database from attempting to guess the passwords. If you've done things correctly, he would have to use a different salt for each person. He can't just start guessing passwords using a site-wide salt and see if it matches anyone. As long as you have a unique salt for each user, you are doing the best you can.

In fact, changing the salt does nothing but give an attacker with access to your database over time MORE information. Now he knows what their password looks like salted two different ways. That could (theoretically) help crack it. For this reason, it would actually be ill advised to change the salt.

2) Https is sufficient. If someone can compromise https, then any additional client side hashing or such will not help. The clients computer is compromised.

3) I think you have a fair understanding of best password practices. Don't overlook other security issues like sql-injection and cross-site scripting.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to change the salt periodically?

No. The salt is a per-user public parameter that servers two purposes. First, it ensures that an attacker cannot build an offline dictionary of passwords to hashes. Second, it ensures two users with the same password have different hashed password entries in the database.

See the [Secure Password Storage Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) and [Secure Password Storage paper](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1R6c9NW6wtoEoT3CS4UVmthw1a6Ex6TGSBaEqDay5U7g) by John Steven of OWASP. It takes you through the entire threat model, and explains why things are done in particular ways.

> The request to the server will be done via https. Does that mean I can assume that I can process all of the hashing and validation logic server side?

This is standard practice, but its a bad idea. Its a bad idea because of all the problems with SSL/TLS and PKI in practice. Though this is common, here's how it fails: the SSL/TLS channel is setup with any server that presents a certificate. The web application then puts the {username, password} on the wire in the plain text using a `basic_auth` scheme. Now the bad guy has the username and password.

There's lots of other problems with doing things this way. Peter Gutmann talks about this problem (and more) in his [Engineering Security](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/pubs/book.pdf) book. He's got a witty sense of humor, so the book is cleverly funny at times, too even though its a technical book.

> Would most folks consider this sufficient, or do I need to consider some hybrid both on client and server side?

If possible, use TLS-PSK (Preshared Key) or TLS-SRP (Secure Remote Password). Both overcome the problems of `basic_auth` schemes, both properly bind the channel, and both provide mutual authentication. There are 80 cipher suites available for TLS-PSK and TLS-SRP, so there's no shortage of algorithms.

> Anything else I am overlooking or need to consider?

Cracking is not the only threat here. More than likely, the guy trying to break into your organization is going to be using one of the top passwords from the millions of passwords gathered from the Adobe breach, the LinkedIn breach, the Last.fm breach, the <favorite here> breach.... For example:

- [25 most-used passwords revealed: Is yours one of them?](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/security/25-most-used-passwords-revealed-is-yours-one-of-them/12427)
- [The 30 Most Popular Passwords Stolen From LinkedIn](http://mashable.com/2012/06/08/linkedin-stolen-passwords-list/)
- [Top 100 Adobe Passwords with Count](http://stricture-group.com/files/adobe-top100.txt)

Why bother brute forcing when you have a list of thousands of top rated passwords to use?

So your **FIRST** best defense is to use a word list that filters a user's bad password choices. That is, don't allow user's to pick weak or known passwords in the first place.

If someone gets away with your password database, then he or she is going to use those same password lists to try and guess your user's passwords. He or she is probably not even going to bother brute forcing because he or she will have recovered so many passwords using a password list.

As I understand it, these word lists are quite small when implemented as a Bloom Filter. They are only KB in size even though there are millions of passwords. See Peter Gutmann's [Engineering Security](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/pubs/book.pdf) for an in depth discussion.